# How do I set the color for an NSAttributedString on iPad?

Tags: ipad, colors, nsattributedstring

I've seen a lot of questions related to colored text answered with "check out `NSAttributedString`", but the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` constant that is defined for Mac OS does not seem to be defined for iOS 3.2+

Answer (score 0):

Use the `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` constant instead.